# APNS certificate for production

Tags: iphone, ios, ssl-certificate, apple-push-notifications, production-environment

I have implemented the apple push notification for development and adhoc testing, it's working fine.Now I am about to submit my iPhone application to app store.

So I want to know what changes I have to do in Server side implementation and APNS certification.

My APNS implementation code in server side for development is as below:

```
public class PushNotification
{
    private static final String HOST = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";
    private static final int PORT = 2195;
    private static final int BADGE = intValue;
    private static String iPhoneId = "hex-digits";
    private static String certificate = "./Development/JavaPNS/src/com/applicationname/pns/privateKey.p12";
    private static String passwd = "password@1234";

.
.
.
.

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change host and certificate only.